# Composable Lensing

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

I have the following Haskell types

```
import Control.Lens
import Data.Map.Lens
import qualified Data.Map as M

type RepoStats = M.Map String (M.Map String RepoStat)
data RepoStat = RepoStat {
  _full_name :: String,
  _bug_count :: Maybe Int,
  _commit_count :: Maybe Int
  }
  deriving (Generic, Show, Eq, Read)
makeLenses ''RepoStat
```

I would like to be able to abstract out the nested checking for the values and giving defaults:

```
makeStat name bug commit =
    RepoStat
    { _full_name = name
    , _bug_count = Just bug
    , _commit_count = Just commit
    }

getRepoStat :: String -> String -> (RepoStat -> Identity RepoStat) -> RepoStats -> Identity RepoStats
getRepoStat k1 k2 = at k1 . non (M.empty) . at k2 . non (makeStat k2 0 0)

fakeMap = M.empty :: RepoStats
setBug = fakeMap & (getRepoStat "a" "b") . bug_count ?~ 4
getBug = fakeMap ^. (getRepoStat "a" "b") . bug_count
```

setBug compiles and works, but getBug does not.

```
test/Spec.hs:65:21: Couldn't match type ‘Identity RepoStats’ …
                   with ‘Const RepoStat RepoStats’
    Expected type: Getting RepoStat RepoStats RepoStat
      Actual type: (RepoStat -> Identity RepoStat)
                   -> RepoStats -> Identity RepoStats
    In the second argument of ‘(^.)’, namely ‘(getRepoStat "a" "b")’
    In the expression: fakeDb ^. (getRepoStat "a" "b")
Compilation failed.
```

Is it possible to abstract out a lens in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's useful to just remove the type signature:

```
getRepoStat k1 k2 = at k1 . non M.empty . at k2 . non (makeStat k2 0 0)
```

Now we can look at the inferred type with `:t getRepoStat` in ghci.

It's a bit messy, chiefly because [`at`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13.2/docs/Control-Lens-At.html) is overloaded:

```
getRepoStat
  :: (Functor f, At m, IxValue m ~ M.Map String RepoStat) =>
     Index m -> String -> (RepoStat -> f RepoStat) -> m -> f m
```

We can recognize though that we return a [`Lens'`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13.2/docs/Control-Lens-Type.html#t:Lens-39-) and we can also restrict the context of the lens to `RepoStats`:

```
getRepoStat :: String -> String -> Lens' RepoStats RepoStat
getRepoStat k1 k2 = at k1 . non M.empty . at k2 . non (makeStat k2 0 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

It sure is. The type signature you specified for `getRepoStat` is its type signature as a [setter](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13.2/docs/Control-Lens-Setter.html). If you want to be able to use it as a [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13.2/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html) in its full generality then the type signature should be

```
getRepoStat :: Functor f => String -> String -> (RepoStat -> f RepoStat) -> RepoStats -> f RepoStats
-- same definition
```

This is probably the inferred type of `getRepoStat`, too.